# Call Function within ForEach Loop

Tags: foreach, swiftui

I simply want to count the number of events that fit an "if" statement within a ForEach loop, but am getting the following error.

I have tried several variations to achieve the task but each has resulted in errors of some description. I'll add that I am a struggling novice!

> Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

The code I'm using right now.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import EventKit

class Summary: ObservableObject {
    @Published var walkCount:Int = 0
    @Published var dayCareCount:Int = 0
    @Published var shortStayCount:Int = 0
    @Published var longStayCount:Int = 0
    @Published var dropInCount:Int = 0
}

struct SummaryView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var eventsRepository = EventsRepository.shared
    @ObservedObject var selectDate = datepicker()
    var summary: Summary
    
    enum BookingType {
        case walk
        case dayCare
        case shortStay
        case longStay
        case dropIn
    }
    
    func countBooking(bookingType: BookingType) {
        switch bookingType {
        case .walk:
            summary.walkCount += 1
        case .dayCare:
            summary.dayCareCount += 1
        case .shortStay:
            summary.shortStayCount += 1
        case .longStay:
            summary.longStayCount += 1
        case .dropIn:
            summary.dropInCount += 1
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GroupBox {
            
            VStack{
                
                //Walks
                HStack{
                    
                    ForEach(eventsRepository.events ?? [], id: \.self) { event in
                        
                        if event.title.contains("Walk") {
                            
                            countBooking(bookingType: .walk) // running function results in error
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Text("Walks:\(summary.walkCount)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ForEach` is a view container, not a control flow. Use instead standard swift `for in` somewhere outside of `body`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForEach` is meant to be used for building repeating content, `body` is just for defining your `View` not for performing any calculations.

The easiest way to calculated the number of walks is to declare a computed property inside SummaryView but outside `body`:

```
var walksCount: Int {
    eventsRepository.events?
        .filter { $0.title.contains("Walk") }
        .count ?? 0
}
```

Then you can than use it inside the `body` like this:

```
 Text("Walks:\(walksCount)")
```